# Why binary String Data not show as PDF in IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I tried

I get some binary string sending a GET request to some API

```
   let BinaryData = await Operations._sendRequest(baseURL + '/getBinaryString/', 'GET');
```

above Request give to me like this string

```
  "%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Length 5076/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x���Kw�F���� Xxa�c� ���\��g��.��E{ ,���-�e����}
................................................................
startxref
5701
%%EOF
"
```

Firstly I try to encode this string

```
 const encoder = new TextEncoder()
 let encodeBinaryData = encoder.encode(BinaryData)
```

Then I convert it to blob

```
 let blob = new Blob([encodeBinaryData],{type: "application/pdf"});
```

Finaly I am going to show this data in **Iframe**

```
  let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
                    
  frame.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 

  let par = document.getElementById('pdf');

  par.appendChild(frame);
```

Now IFrame is empty, It not show the data.Above binary has a table data. I can sent the following responceType to API, But I dont want to use that way

```
 responceType:"blob"
```

if I send the responceType as blob I can get tha data as BLOB and send it to iframe and show as PDF I can see my all data there.

But I want to show the PDF data using above code. I tested if I can show the string in iframe

```
let str = "Hello World"
let encodeBinaryData = encoder.encode(str)
let blob = new Blob([encodeBinaryData],{type: "text/plain"});
```

Then I can see correct string there, EX: Hello world

But If I use `{type: "application/pdf"}` I cant see anything

how Can I fix this problem? **(I am using pure HTML)**

Comment: `responce` should be spelt `response`

Comment: What happens if you put the `BinaryData` directly into the blob, instead of via the encoder? i.e. `let blob = new Blob([BinaryData],{type: "application/pdf"});`

Comment: @Matt Ellen
In that time also iframe was empty

Comment: Using the `TextEncoder` is not the way to go because it outputs UTF-8 bytes and PDF bytes are not UTF-8 bytes. What is wrong with setting the `responseType` to blob?

Comment: If we set responseType to blob it give me blob data and I can show the PDF in frame there is a no problem with that way, But my question was why I cant use above method?

Comment: Oh, well, PDFs aren't text, so converting them to text will break them.

Comment: NO I am didn't convert it to text. I got binary data then it encode and make as blob then show it in iframe

So if we send responseType:"Blob" to API it give us blob data and we can show it in Iframe (this is work)

According to both methods I am using additional thing is encoding that's it, only difference is that , So what was the problem I cant understand

Comment: UTF-8 bytes are a way of encoding text. PDFs are not text. Converting a PDF to UTF-8 bytes will break it.

Comment: So have any solution except using responceType:"blob"

Comment: No. I am assuming your `_sendRequest` defaults to a respon**s**eType of text, so your PDF will be mangled before it arrives at the client.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering and spend some time for this